# Laravel, How to retrieve parent records with certain Pivot table values belongsToMany

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, has-and-belongs-to-many

How can I retrieve all records of my model based on certain ID's in my pivot table?

I have the following 3 tables

users;
id,
name

stats;
id,
name

stats_selected;
user_id,
stats_id

**Model**

User.php

```
public function stats()
{
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\stats', 'stats_selected', 'user_id', 'stats_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

**Controller**

```
        // Get all users with example of stats ID's
        $aFilterWithStatsIDs = [1,10,13];

        $oUser = User::with(['stats' => function ($query) use($aFilterWithStatsIDs ) {
                    $query->whereIn('stats_id', $aFilterWithStatsIDs);
                }])
                ->orderBy('name', 'desc')
                ->get()
```

This outputs just all the users. Btw, fetching users with there stats and saving those selected stats into the DB is not a problem. That works fine with the above lines.

But how do I retrieve **only** the users which has certain stats_id's within them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how do I retrieve only the users which has certain stats_id's within them?

Use a `whereHas` conditional.

```
User::whereHas('stats', function ($stats) use ($aFilterWithStatsIDs) {
    $stats->whereIn('id', $aFilterWithStatsIDs);
});
```